# Google maps wants a login now? Is there a way around this?

Tags: google-maps, privacy

I've managed to get away with running my Galaxy S without every hooking it up to a Gmail account, but sometime in the last couple of weeks (I think following an OS update from Sprint) Maps started objecting that I'm not logged in.

It's a little unnerving -- why do I need to be logged in to search for an address?

I'd love any suggestions for getting around this. Happy to root my phone. I've got OSM installed, but it doesn't do address searches unless I'm missing something.

Comment: If you can find the APK somewhere you could try downgrading Maps.  I think you should be able to just install it over top without rooting.

Comment: If you find yourself hampered by Google's requirements, you can just set up a bogus GMail account that you don't use for anything else and will only be associated with your device without containing any of your personal information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your three options are probably:

1. Downgrade Maps
2. Use the browser-based Google maps (perhaps in incognito mode if you're paranoid)
3. Use some other map application

Regarding OSM, I think they don't have an official app, so you could also try to use an app that uses their data. The [OSM web site](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) allows address searches, so that may just not be implemented in the app you're using. There's a bunch of OSM compatible apps and their features listed [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android).

Comment: I'd been using Osmdroid, which really doesn't work that well, but I finally started testing OsmAnd, which works great. I got it here: http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=osmand&fdid=net.osmand.plus&fdpage=1